# How to remove duplicate files using Apache Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a couple of EC2 servers set-up, with the same EFS mounted on each of these instances.

Have also setup Apache Nifi independently on each of the 2 machines. Now, when I try to make a data flow to copy files from the EFS mounted folder, I get duplicated files on both the servers.

Is there some way in Apache Nifi using which I can churn out duplicate items, since  both of them are firing at the same time. Cron is not useful enough as at some point the servers will collide at the same time.

Comment: organize nifi instances into cluster, so you'll be able to set only current primary node for a specific processor to ingest file .

Comment: @daggett I want to avoid single point of failure, that is why I can't ingest from only one node

Comment: first- if node fails - another works as primary. without cluster you have to use cache server, database, or other system that will help you to remove (prevent) duplicates.

Comment: alright, will give Nifi Cluster a try, any good resources you know to get started for cluster?

Answer (score 2):

For Detecting Duplicate file you can use DetectDuplicate Processor.

[image]